# Mocha test: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I'm not sure if this is a TS setting or what that needs to be tweaked or something else.  I've already looked at this, it did not help me: [Mocha + TypeScript: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60993812/mocha-typescript-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) and these posts about using `<script src="file1.js" type="module"></script>` makes no sense, I'm running tests here.

I run my test with mocha `-r ts-node/register src/test/**/*.spec.tsx -r src/test/compiler.ts  --color -w`

And I get an error for `import { MemoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";`:

`Cannot use import statement outside a module`

**featured.company.group.tsx**

```
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { expect, mount, React } from "../../test.imports";
import { FeaturedCompanyGroup, FormattedFeaturedCompany } from "../../../client/Company/FeaturedCompanies";

describe("Featured Company Group", () => {
    const country: Country = {
        id: 0,
        name: "string",
        images: {
            flag: "string"
        }
    };
...
```

I'm using:

```
"node": "14.x"
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"@types/mocha": "^8.0.0",
"@types/mocha": "^8.0.0",
```

I have a root ./tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
        "outDir": "./build",
    "target": "ES2020",                     /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2020",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],                      /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": false,                     /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
//      "checkJs": true,                     /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false,                   /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "rootDir": "./",                     /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
        "removeComments": true,              /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "strict": true,                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
        "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
//    "rootDirs": ["."],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],                      /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
        "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
//      "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "/node_modules",
        "/src/server",
        "/src/client/js/ink-config.js",
        "**/test",
        "dist"
  ]
}
```

and I have a /src/test/**tsconfig.json**.  (I don't think this is actually extending my root for some reason, it doesn't appear to be affecting this tsconfig):

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": true,
        "module": "es2020",
        "target": "es2020",
        "types": ["node","mocha", "chai", "react"],
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "compileOnSave": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["./**/*spec.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules","./build"]
}
```

Comment: Do you have `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`?  This is how Node.js knows a `.js` file is an ES module.  See the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules) for more info on how to use ES modules.

Comment: yes but it didn't make any difference

Comment: these tests were running just fine before renaming them to spec.ts

Answer (score -3):

Looks like you’re using “watch” mode, which needs the `extensions` option as per the [ts-node docs](https://npm.im/docs).

Comment: also it doesn't matter if I am in watch mode or not, I still get this error